# como crear na instancia en axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

quiero configurar axios para hacer las peticiones mas ordenadas

```
const instance = Axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.38/8080',
   timeout: 5000,
   headers: {
      'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("token")
   }
})
```

esta es mi instancia, censilla, lo que esta pasando es que tengo un `useEffect` que esta haciendo una peticion pero la url a la que se esta enviando no es a la que estoy configurando en la instancia

```
useEffect(()=>{

async function cargarUsuario() {
  if(GetToken(1)){
    setCargandoUsuario(false);
    return;
  }
  try {
    const { data: usuario } = await Axios.get("/api/usuario")
    setUsuario(usuario)
    setCargandoUsuario(false)
  } catch (errors) {
    throw new Error(errors);
  }
}

cargarUsuario()

},[])
```

mi pregunta es, donde tengo que instanciar la constante `instance`, por que no se esta leyendo las configuraciones, las peticiones se estan mandando al localhost:3000 pero esa no es la url que quiero

Answer (score 0):

Hola bueno a primera vista veo que tienes axios en mayusculas y la constante instance no la estas llamando sigues usando axios

```
const { data: usuario } = await instance.get("/api/usuario")
```

te dejo este enlace que me ayudo mucho a comprender esta biblioteca espero te sirva la info saludos

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/what-is-axios-and-how-to-use-it-with-react-1470d19e1b83